# Fetch all rows that column_id is in the array of id's, then order by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying this, not sure if I am doing this correctly:

```
User.where("region_id => ?", region_ids).order("id ASC")

region_ids = [1234,234322,234324,2343,....]
```

Also, will this work if the region_ids is empty (not null, but empty)

I am seeing an error:

```
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> NULL) ORDER BY id ASC' at line 1:
```

When I was in debugger mode, I output the region_ids and it was [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up Ruby and SQL syntax within the string. What you want is more like `("region_id in (?)", region_ids)` or `({ "region_id" => region_ids })`.

Comment: mostly right, but the first example should be ("region_id in (?)", region_ids).

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't recall off the top of my head if/when Rails did this automatically.

Comment: if region_ids is [], does it show up as NULL in the query?  it looks to be for me...

Comment: @Blankman My assumption would be that it would generate SQL like: `region_id in ()` if region_ids is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the order of the two lines, region_ids should be set before the User.where
becuase the way it is now region_ids is NULL when you call where().